# Send intent/answer back from fragment

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-fragments

I have two activities A,B. A starts B for result. B contains a fragment.

In the fragment I have a static class which extends view so I can draw on it and this handles the touches. How can I send back the results from the static class->fragment->B activity->A activity?

Which code snippets do you need me to provide?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are asking a few different questions:

1. How to send a result back from `Activity` B to A?

   Use `setResult` method before invoking `finish` in the B activity to provide the returning code and intent.
2. How to send result from a `Fragmant`to `Activity` A?

   Use `getActivity()` method to obtain a handle on the parent `Activity` (in your example B) and then follow the point 1
3. How to send **anything** from a static class to a dynamic object in Android

   This is simply not possible. Using static classes is not the best OOD ;-)

Hope this helps

Comment: 1 and 2 is working as intended, I just cant send the information from the static class, and you say it is not possible. What is the correct way than to draw on a fragment, get touches and than send back the intent? Sorry if I am not the most precise I just can't explain it well :D

Comment: How about creating an instance of your `View` class on `Fragment` creation or even better when it gets attached to the `Activity`?!

Comment: Could you put an example project somewhere on github?